Expect script with Xargs and multiple parameters
I have an expect script that will SSH into a list of routers.
The expect script works on a list of routers in a file and is called from a bash script with xargs.
Bash : script get-rtr.sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xargs -P 10 -L 1 -r ./get-rtr-expect.sh < ./router_list

The expect script will SSH into 10 routers at a time, until it completes the list.
Expect : script get-rtr-expect.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set IPaddress [lindex $argv 0]
log into routers and get configs etc

I want to pass 2 more arguments (the same 2 for every router) to the expect script from the bash script, so that ultimately the expect script takes 3 args, and it will look like this:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set IPaddress [lindex $argv 0]
set foo [lindex $argv 1]
set bar [lindex $argv 2]
log into routers and get configs etc

How can I pass those 2 extra args to each instance of the expect script?
thanks
UPDATE.
I came up with a really ugly way to do it:
Add to the bash script get-rtr.sh:
> router_list_temp
list=`cat router_list`
for i in `echo $list`
do
echo $i $foo $bar >> router_list_temp
done

/usr/bin/xargs -P 10 -L 1 -r ./get-rtr-expect.sh  < ./router_list_temp

> router_list_temp

I am looping thru the router list, and writing to a new file with the args added. Then feed the new list to the expect script, each line of the line is arg0 arg1 and arg 2.
Then wipe it clean at the end.
I don't like this at all. I don't want to create a temp file, but it seems to be working.
All better ideas are welcome.
If router_list_temp could be an array of routers with 2 args, rather than a file, that would be better .... it would all live in RAM.
but I don't know how to create and array or pass it to an expect script.

I figured out the answer
I put the routers into an array, by looping through the router list, each element of the array has 3 args, router, foo and bar ... then feed that array to the expect script.
my_array=()
while IFS= read -r name; do
    my_array+=("$name $foo $bar")
done < /router_list

printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}" | xargs   -P 10 -L 1 -r ./get-rtr-expect.sh

Works well.

-L 1 is to pass the words from 1 line as separate arguments to the command. Here, it seems you want to pass the whole line as one argument, so it's more -d '\n' -n 1 you want.
But here, you could also use the -I PLACEHOLDER option as:
xargs -P10 -I@ -d '\n' -a /router_list ./get-rtr-expect.sh @ "$foo" "$bar"

(assuming neither $foo nor $bar contains @).
-I implies -r. -a, -r, -P, -d are GNU extensions, -r in POSIX since the 2024 edition, -P planned for inclusion in the next major version.
If the lines of /router_list, $foo, $bar don't contain whitespace nor quotes nor backslashes, then you could use -L 1 if you appended the contents of $foo and $bar, space separated to each line:
APPEND=" $foo $bar" awk '{print $0 ENVIRON["APPEND"]}' /router_list |
  xargs -P10 -rL1 ./get-rtr-expect.sh


Assuming you want to add two static arguments in the call to your expect script:
#!/bin/sh
exec xargs -P 10 -L 1 -r ./get-rtr-expect.sh "$foo" "$bar" <./router_list

This adds "$foo" and "$bar" to the script at the start of the list of arguments (these variables need to be set, either in the environment of the shell script or by the shell script itself).  The 3rd argument will be added from the input file by xargs.
As xargs is a standard utility, I removed the unnecessary path to the utility.  I also added exec as we don't need the script to hang around after starting xargs; instead, replace the shell process with it. The script is now a sh script rather than a bash script as we don't use any bash-specific features in it.
In the expect script, you then receive the two new arguments along with the 3rd one from xargs:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set foo [lindex $argv 0]
set bar [lindex $argv 1]
set IPaddress [lindex $argv 2]
log into routers and get configs etc

